# Call Chrome from the Command Line without Showing UI

Tags: google-chrome, cmd

As part of a console application, I'd like to hit a URL in Chrome without showing the browser window. Is this possible?

I'm already using `/B` with the command prompt:

`start "" /B "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "google.com"`

Answer (score 0):

You need vbscript to hide a window.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

msgbox FormatNumber(WshShell.Run("cmd /k dir c:\windows\*.*", 0, false))
```

Something like

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run wscript.Arguments(0), 0, false
```

in a vbs file. Use

```
C:\Users\User>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\RunHidden.vbs" "notepad"
```